# What are the steps to do before clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

I know that continuous variables needs to be normalized or transformed as a first step in clustering. But are there any other steps that needs to be done before clustering? This was asked in an interview. So I am just curious to know.

Comment: 1) Though normalizing and transformation may be useful in some (or even many) cases, I don't think they are required steps. 2) Clustering is a very broad topic, so you probably need to provide a lot more detail if you want good advice.

Comment: Thanks! I want to know about what data preprocessing steps, feature selection steps will be carried out in general. Like how do we answer this question when asked in an interview

Comment: As I said, if you narrow this down to a specific problem and add details, you are more likely to get good answers.

Comment: There are many tutorials on the internet. It would be useful if you could make your question more specific. For starters I recommend reading this: https://uc-r.github.io/hc_clustering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide which one is the appropriate similarity function, taking into account what kind of data you have available. For example, although in most case for clustering with k-means the Euclidean Distance seems to be fine, when you text data using the representation of bag of words then the appropriate similarity fucntion is Cosine Similarity instead of Euclidean Distance.

Also you could exclude the outliers. For example k-means clustering algorithm is based on centroids for each cluster, so the mean could be sensitive to outliers.

You could decide the number of the clusters or for which values of k you are going to perform the clustering algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Identify a reliable measure to quantify similarity.

You can't just run clustering on data and expect to get anything meaningful. Clustering quality depends heavily on the quality of your distance function, so this needs to be very carefully chosen first.